# How can we escape the folder name having space in its name when passed from variable ?

Tags: java

I need to call a bat file from my Java program and the path of the bat file contains folder having spaces in its name. I am able to escape these folder name but the problem is that the path of the bat file is coming from a variable and I don't know how to escape the variable values.

Path of the bat file:- C:/My Data/batfile.bat
My code to escape the space:

This works fine

```
String t = "C://\"My Data\"//BatFile.bat";
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait "+t);
```

This doesn't work

```
String t = path+"//BatFile.bat";
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait "+t);
```

path variable in above line contains the bat file path "C:/My Data"

Suggestions ?

Comment: What is the value of `path` in the second scenario?

Comment: try to escape the blank with backslash

Comment: @Jens If you're right, then he could do a `replaceAll(" ", "\\\\ ")`

Comment: You can escape whole path `String t = "\"" + path +"//BatFile.bat\"", if the path is not escaped already

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am not sure it can be "\\ " or "\\\\ "

Comment: I would suggest add cd in your command argument and then execute your bat. And it will be better to use ProcessBuilder for such case.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with the solution. I have accepted Peter answer below . @jan.supol your answer was also very useful. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do put it in quotes.

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd", "/c", "start /wait \""+t+"\"");
```

Note: this doesn't work if the text also includes quotes, though a path shouldn't do so.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. I have accepted the answer. Cheers :)